# Finding the Center Z(G) for the group G of all invertible Matrices in M2(R) under Multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra

So i know that basically i need to find which matrices in M2(R) that commute with all other invertible matrices in M2(R)

so Z(G) = { AX=XA for all X belongs to G }

how can i find those A matrices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $M\in Z(G)$, we have that 
$$M\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\0&1\end{array}\right]M$$
so, letting $M=\left[\begin{array}{cc}m_{11}&m_{12}\\m_{21}&m_{22}\end{array}\right]$,
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}m_{11}&m_{11}+m_{12}\\m_{21}&m_{21}+m_{22}\end{array}\right]
=\left[\begin{array}{cc}m_{11}+m_{21}&m_{12}+m_{22}\\m_{21}&m_{22}\end{array}\right]
$$
What does the above equation allow you to dedude about the entries of $M$?

Comment: But this is the centralizer not the center

Comment: The center is contained in the centralizer of this element. The above computations therefore tell you necessary conditions for $M$ to be in the center. All that's left is to show these are sufficient.